# How do you go from a sip.voidptr (QImage.constBits()) to a ctypes void or char pointer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, ctypes

I'm using python and of course you can't loop through every pixel of a large image very quickly, so I defer to a C DLL.

I want to do something like this:

```
img = QImage("myimage.png").constBits()
imgPtr = c_void_p(img)
found = ctypesDLL.myImageSearchMethod(imgPtr, width, height)
```

But this line
    imgPtr = c_void_p(img)
yelds

> builtins.TypeError: cannot be converted to pointer

I don't need to modify the bits.  Please teach me your Jedi ways in this area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html#sip.voidptr), `sip.voidptr.__int__()` method

> returns the address as an integer

while `c_void_p` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_void_p) says

> The constructor accepts an optional integer initializer.

So you should be able to build a `c_void_p` passing the return value of `sip.voidptr.__int__()` method to its constructor:

```
imgPtr = c_void_p(img.__int__())
```

I tested this solution this way:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL("/usr/lib/libtestlib.so")

image = QtGui.QImage("so.png")
bits = image.constBits()
bytes = image.bytesPerLine()
lib.f(c_void_p(bits.__int__()), c_int(image.width()), c_int(image.height()), c_int(bytes))
```

Which works fine with a function like:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <QImage>
extern "C" {

    void f(unsigned char * c, int width, int height, int bpl)
    {
        printf("W:%d H:%d BPL:%d\n", width, height, bpl);
        QImage image(c, width, height, bpl, QImage::Format_RGB32);
        image.save("test.bmp");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a savior!