# Working with `PyQt5.QtCore.QLibrary` in Python: How to cast a `sip.voidptr` to a function?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgis, python-sip

I am trying to port (some of) the logic of [void QgsPluginManager::getCppPluginsMetadata()](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/pluginmanager/qgspluginmanager.cpp#L419) from QGIS from C++ to Python.

In C++, the relevant section looks about as follows:

```
/* `lib` is a path (string) to a QGIS plugin shared object file, e.g. `/lib/qgis/plugins/libtopolplugin.so` */
QLibrary *myLib = new QLibrary( lib );
bool loaded = myLib->load();
if ( !loaded ) { /* handle error */ }
name_t *pName = ( name_t * ) cast_to_fptr( myLib->resolve( "name" ) );
if ( pName ) { QgsDebugMsg( "Plugin name: " + pName() ); }
```

`QLibrary` is used to load the shared object file. Once it is loaded, function pointers are resolved, casted to actual functions and then called. In the above example, `pName` would return the name of the plugin as a string.

In Python, tried the following:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore

lib = '/lib/qgis/plugins/libtopolplugin.so'
myLib = QtCore.QLibrary(lib)

loaded = myLib.load()
if not loaded:
    print("Failed to load library!")
    sys.exit()

print( myLib.resolve( "name" ) )
print( myLib.resolve( "name" )() )

print('The end.')
```

I got the following output:

```
<sip.voidptr object at 0x7fa046b214b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_QLibrary.py", line 17, in <module>
    print( myLib.resolve( "name" )() )
TypeError: 'sip.voidptr' object is not callable
```

It makes sense that I can not call a `sip.voidptr` directly - I'd need to cast it to a function somehow. Is this even possible (with `sip` or other tools) in Python? If yes, how?

Comment: Just came across `sip.wrapinstance`. Maybe it does the trick somehow ...

Comment: What do you need the return type to be?

Comment: @Xilpex The return type of the `name` method is actually a `QString`. PyQt5 automatically maps `QString`s to Python strings (UTF-8), so I'd expect a Python string.

Comment: I don't know if this will help but look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689778/how-do-you-go-from-a-sip-voidptr-qimage-constbits-to-a-ctypes-void-or-char-p

Comment: What do you get when you add `print( myLib.resolve( "name" ).ascapsule() )`?